# Can we see the posts of a page that a particular page likes via fb api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a fb page and i have liked some of the other pages like laughing colors.. Now as if i go in my insight tab then it shows the top posts of those pages that i like. For example, look at the image below:

[top post from a page that my page likes](http://prntscr.com/a4fg6d)

I also want to read the data (top posts) from the page that my page likes. Can it be done using fb api? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get list of pages that your page likes = that is going to be `GET <page_id>/likes` in graph api. (try it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Loop through the pages from step 1 and get their last post via `<liked_page_id>/posts`.

Overall you will need to play with the API but it should not be very hard.

Comment: But what if i want only the top posts from the pages that my page likes?

Comment: You will have to filter them by yourself or use some advanced graph api filtering (no idea if its supported, there used to be FQL which was much better at filtering but it is no longer supported).